# Get a row counts from a file based in a list field python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a file read in my code, then I got a year field from the source in a list and now I need go throughout the file by every year to find out how many rows I have per year.

I did the exercise in Excel and I'm expecting the output below:

[image]

My code:

```
input_f = open("C:\\Users\\P928260\\Downloads\\ssa-pop3-eng.csv","r")
next(input_f)


years_unique = []
controler = False

while(controler != True):
        counter_rows = 0
        #Get a list with the read years
        for line in input_f:
            item = line.split(',')
            year_f = item[0][:4]
            if (year_f not in years_unique):
                years_unique.append(year_f)


        input_f.close()

        input_f = open("C:\\Users\\P928260\\Downloads\\ssa-pop3-eng.csv","r")
        next(input_f)


        for year in years_unique:
            for line in input_f:
                item = line.split(',')
                year_f = item[0][:4]
                if (year == year_f):
                    counter_rows +=1

            print(year,counter_rows)


    controler = True
```

My current output is only printing the same row account that is right for 2012 but is not including the other years. I know I'm close. I appreciate your help guys.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you want to change in your code.

Use context managers where necessary. You can implicitly manage file closing with it whether or not an exception occurs.

You can also use `defaultdict` in the `collections` library. It helps to set a default factory for setting the initial value of any key accessed in the dictionary for the first time. In this case, we use the `int` builtin function to set the default value as `0`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

year_count = defaultdict(int)

with open("C:\\Users\\P928260\\Downloads\\ssa-pop3-eng.csv","r") as file:    
    for line in file:
        year, *rest = line.split(',')
        year = year.strip()  # clean year
        year_count[year] += 1

for year, count in year_count.items():
    print(year, count)
```

Comment: what means *_ ?

Comment: I've renamed it to `*rest`. It binds to the other items in the list resulting from splitting the string. `year` binds to the first item in that list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the second loop specifically in the inner loop which runs only once; you can iterate over a file object only once (unless you `seek` to the beginning of the file on each iteration).

```
for year in years_unique:
            for line in input_f:
                item = line.split(',')
                year_f = item[0][:4]
                if (year == year_f):
                    counter_rows +=1
```

The '2012' is the first item in `years_unique` list, so the inner loop will run and every occurrence in the file will cause the `counter_rows` to increase by 1, but on next iterations, the `input_f` is already exhausted, so to speak, and no other increments occur.

Also, notice that you didn't reset `counter_rows` on each iteration.

An easier approach is to use a `dict` in one loop, here's an example:

```
input_f = open("YOUR_FILE")
next(input_f)

years = {}

for line in input_f:
    items = line.split(",")
    year = items[0][:4]
    years.setdefault(year, 0)
    years[year] += 1

input_f.close()
print(years)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out in this way!

```
input_f = open("C:\\Users\\P928260\\Downloads\\ssa-pop3-eng.csv","r")
output_f = open("C:\\Users\\P928260\\Downloads\\output.txt","w")

next(input_f)


years_unique = []


for line in input_f:
    item = line.split(',')
    year_f = item[0][:4]

    if (year_f not in years_unique):
        years_unique.append(year_f)


input_f.close()



for year in years_unique:
    counter_rows =0
    input_f = open("C:\\Users\\P928260\\Downloads\\ssa-pop3-eng.csv","r")      
    next(input_f)   
    for line in input_f:
        item = line.split(',')
        year_f = item[0][:4]
        if (year_f in year):
            counter_rows += 1
    input_f.close()            
    print(year,counter_rows)
```

Comment: you are opening and closing file len(years_unique) times. This is not necessary and can be done in one go as @Oluwafemi shows.

Comment: I know mine is more expensive, I'm trying to understand @Oluwafemi approach. thanks guys.